# When do sentence fragments take the accusative?

Tags: accusative

This is a simple exchange I had [on twitter](https://twitter.com/hugoestr/status/947491604281085952):

> a: Mi estas lacata.
>
> b: Dormu!
>
> a: Bona ideo. Mi dormis. Dankon!

Why not "`Bonan ideon. Mi dormis. Dankon`!"?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe because it means :
(Estas) bona ideo. Mi dormis. (Mi donas) dankon (al vi)!

Comment: This is correct. In Esperanto wishes such as ”bonan tagon” etc. always take the accusative as “mi deziras (al vi)” is implicit.

Comment: The full sentence would be ***Tio** estas bona ideo*. Without the *tio* it just means "there is a good idea (out there somewhere.)"